# Invoking functions indirectly (using a string) in BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, conditionals, programming, strings

Is it possible to do indirect function calls in BibTeX styles, i.e. to get the function name from a field in the `.bib`? `EXECUTE` would be able to do that but these statements don't work within functions(?).

My current workaround is to fetch the field name, compare it with a string literal and call the respective function if it matches. This works but it is awful (so probably right since it's a `.bst`? :)
For example:

```
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ this.to.prev.status
  this.status.std
  type empty$
    {
      % Leave warnings to callers
      ""
    }
    {
      type "bthesis" =
      {
        bbl.bthesis
      }
      {
        type "mthesis" =
        {
          bbl.mthesis
        }
        {
          type "phdthesis" =
          {
            bbl.phdthesis
          }
          {
            type "Unknown thesis type " swap$ * ", printing it verbatim" * warning$
            type
          }
        if$
        }
      if$
      }
    if$
    }
  if$
  cap.status.std
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed, you cannot.

BibTeX, same as TeX, saves functions in a hash table. TeX has `\csname<control-sequence>\endcsname` to fetch the hash table entry that corresponds to the string literal `<control-sequence>`.
BibTeX does not :-)

To have that, you'd need to add that functionality to BibTeX itself (which may not be the most fun task).

---

As a consolation prize, here's a `strcase` function which might make that task of yours less boring.

The syntax is:

```
{ Other cases } "{OTHERWISE}"
{ Case n } <string n>
...
{ Case 2 } <string 2>
{ Case 1 } <string 1>
<string> strcase
```

The function `strcase` will compare the `<string>` against each `<string n>` (from `1` to `n`: this is reverse polish notation, so it will read the items backwards), and once a match is found, the code for `Case n` is executed, and the rest is discarded (even if multiple strings match). If no match was found, the `Other cases` code is executed. You can use as many `{ Case n } <string n>` pairs as you wish, but the final `{ Other cases } "{OTHERWISE}"` is mandatory, so that the function knows where to stop.

Your case could be written as (with a prior check for `type missing$`:

```
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ this.to.prev.status
  this.status.std
  type missing$
    {
      % Do something when type is not given
    }
    {
      { "Unknown thesis type "  type ", printing it verbatim" * * warning$ }
                        "{OTHERWISE}"
      { bbl.bthesis }   "bthesis"
      { bbl.mthesis }   "mthesis"
      { bbl.phdthesis } "phdthesis"
      type strcase
    }
  if$
  cap.status.std
}
```

Here's a compilable example with the `.bst` code:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bst}
ENTRY { type name } { } { }
INTEGERS { strcase.next } % the code requires an integer
STRINGS { s t } % and two strings
FUNCTION { not }
  {   { #0 }
      { #1 }
    if$
  }
FUNCTION { pop.next } { swap$ pop$ }
FUNCTION { strcase.end }
  { #0 'strcase.next :=
    #1
      swap$
      'skip$
    if$
  }
FUNCTION { strcase }
  { #1 'strcase.next :=
      { strcase.next }
      { 's :=
        't :=
        s t =
          {   { swap$ "{OTHERWISE}" = not }
              { pop.next }
            while$
            pop.next
            strcase.end
          }
          { "{OTHERWISE}" t =
              { strcase.end }
              { pop$ s }
            if$
          }
        if$
      }
    while$
  }
FUNCTION { thesis }
  {
    type missing$
      { "Type missing for entry " cite$ * warning$ }
      {
        { "Unknown thesis type "  type ", printing it verbatim" * * warning$ }
          "{OTHERWISE}"
        { "This is a bachelor thesis" warning$ } "bthesis"
        { "This is a master thesis" warning$ }   "mthesis"
        { "This is a doctor thesis" warning$ } "phdthesis"
        type strcase
      }
    if$
  }
READ
ITERATE {call.type$}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@thesis{bach, type = {bthesis}}
@thesis{mast, type = {mthesis}}
@thesis{doct, type = {phdthesis}}
@thesis{unkn, type = {unknown}}
@thesis{void, name = {me}}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite*
\bibliography{test}
\bibliographystyle{test}
\end{document}
```